# Proving $\left| \zeta (z) \Pi_{k=1}^{N} (1-\frac{1}{p_k^z}) -1 \ \right| \leq \sum_{n=p_{N+1}}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{\Re{z}}}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to prove that $\left| \zeta (z) \Pi_{k=1}^{N} (1-\frac{1}{p_k^z}) -1 \ \right| \leq \sum_{n=p_{N+1}}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{\Re{z}}}$
where $\zeta (z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^z}, \quad \Re (z) > 1$ is the Riemann-zeta function and $p_1=2, p_2=3, p_3=5, \ldots$ are the prime numbers.

I've shown it for $N=1$ and think there should be some inductive argument, but I can't seem to find it, and I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around what I'm working with.

I've tried this:
\begin{align}
\left| \zeta (z) \Pi_{k=1}^{N+1} (1-\frac{1}{p_k^z}) -1 \ \right|
&= \left| \zeta (z) \Pi_{k=1}^{N} (1-\frac{1}{p_k^z}) - \frac{1}{p_{N+1}^z}
\zeta (z) \Pi_{k=1}^{N} (1-\frac{1}{p_k^z}) -1 \ \right|\\
&\leq \left| \sum_{n=p_{N+1}}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{\Re{z}}} - \frac{1}{p_{N+1}^z}
\zeta (z) \Pi_{k=1}^{N} (1-\frac{1}{p_k^z})  \right|
\end{align}
but I'm not sure where to go from here nor whether I'm on the right track. Help would be appreciated.